# Is the turn of speech "stand: September 16, 2018" correct?

Tags: expressions, time

I'm writing on my website:

> This German / English Word List in *Excel* contains 1593 German words. If you need more words, you can have my German-English word list with 27449 words (**stand: September 16, 2018**).

Is the turn of speech "stand: September 16, 2018" correct? By it I want to say that as of September 16, 2018, there are 27449 words in my word list, but in the future there may be even more.

Comment: So why don't you say "as of September 16, 2018?"

Comment: Is this the German word "stand" by any chance? Are you asking if it means the same in English? If not, why did you choose the word?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got German and English mixed up yesterday late at night. I looked up the phrase in the dictionary today and it turned out the following: Stand ... [Datum / Uhrzeit] = as of ... [date / time]

Answer (score 1):

Second, if there is some legitimate question being posed here, "standing at x on y" is probably what is meant, but that expression is not so idiomatic as a simple "x as of y." I have forgotten much of my German, but it is frequently possible to translate German literally into English so that it is comprehensible without being idiomatic. My wife's grandmother moved to the US in her thirties, and she and I used to laugh at literal translations from one language to the other. (This was only if the phrase was proper for women to say to men under the conventionss of Wilhelmine Germany. For example, she absolutely refused to discuss certain phrases that I found in Brecht. She might giggle, but I had to consult my father-in-law about meaning.)